# google chrome browser doesn't remember the back point

Tags: google-chrome

i don't know how to say this, but i'll try to explain what I wanted to ask you guys. I have an imac and google chrome browser which i browse everyday.

Whenever i browser on a page and scroll down somewhere in the middle or just a little bit down the page and click on a link or whatever then i wanna go back to the page that has that link I have just clicked, but my google chrome browser doesn't take me to that point i've just browsed, it takes me to the very top of the page which is very annoying.

So my question is, how do i make it remember the point so whenever i click on any link within any where of the page and come back to that same point?

Sometime it does take me back to the same point but most of the time don't. Not so sure why. I always use magic mouse to swipe it back though.

Please any ideas guys.

Comment: Does it work if you use backspace (or the equivilent key on mac).  Ie have you checked whether this behavior is related to the mouse?

Comment: Oh yes it works if i use Backspace but if i use swipe gesture on magic mouse, it doesn't. It's like 2/10 times works. Any ideas why it doesn't? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing Magic Mouse has a buggy approach to going back. I remember seeing this problem in a few places with mobile browsers. It's really frustrating when you're looking through a long list of posts.

You can use Alt-Left to go back in Chrome, but as far as Magic Mouse goes, I guess you'll have to file a bug report and hope they can, and do, fix it.

Comment: I've just tried this on my macbook, and Chrome seems to remember my place when I use the back arrows, but not gestures (three finger swiping). What the heck Google...